# Order of a group exercise

Tags: group-theory

> Let $(G, \cdot)$ be a group, $H \leq G$ and $g \in G$ such that $ord(g)  = n$ and $g^m \in H$, where $m,n \in \mathbb{N^*}$ are two coprime numbers. Show that $g \in H.$

Comment: **Hint:** Show that $\langle g\rangle$ is contained in $H$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As $m,n$ are coprime, we can find $r,s\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $rm+sn=1$. Then $g^1=g^{rm+sn}=g^{rm}\cdot g^{sn}$. Notice that $g^{rm}=(g^m)^r\in H$, because $g^m$ is in $H$ and $g^{rn}=(g^n)^r=1^r=1\in H$. Thus $g\in H$.

Answer (score 2):

Both the posted answers invoke Bezout's lemma, so here's one without using it.

We know that $g^m\in H$, so we know that $\langle g^m\rangle\subset H$.

Now, suppose $g^{am},g^{bm}\in\langle g^m\rangle$ are equal ($a,b\in\Bbb Z$). Then, we have,

$$g^{am}=g^{bm}\iff g^{(a-b)m}=e\iff n\mid (a-b)m$$

Since $m,n$ are coprime, we have $n\mid a-b$, thus implying that the elements of set $A=\{g^m,g^{2m},\ldots,g^{(n-1)m},e\}$ are pairwise distinct and has cardinality $n$. Notice that $A\subseteq\langle g\rangle$ which also has cardinality $n$. Hence, we can conclude that $A=\langle g\rangle\subseteq H$, thus $g\in H$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $n$ and $m$ are coprime so there exists integers $x,y$ such that $mx+ny=1$. Using this we get
$$g=g^1=g^{mx+ny}=(g^m)^x \, (g^n)^y.$$
Since both $g^m$ and $g^n(=e)$ are in the subgroup $H$, therefore by closure $g \in H$.